# How to define blocks of elements in a vector to zero and looping over the next blocks?

Tags: r, loops

I have a large vector which I would like to multiply with a matrix. This is easy to do in r. The issue here is that I would like to define certain blocks of elements within the vector to zero, multiply this with the matrix which then creates a vector, and then repeat for the next block of elements leaving the first block with the original values.

I give a small example of what I'm trying to do. "a" is a vector and "b" a matrix:

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, ncol = 6)
```

a
`[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6`

b

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    7   13   19   25   31
[2,]    2    8   14   20   26   32
[3,]    3    9   15   21   27   33
[4,]    4   10   16   22   28   34
[5,]    5   11   17   23   29   35
[6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36
```

In this example, there are 3 blocks of zeroes for "a":

```
a1 <- c(0 , 0, a[3:6])              #giving              [1] 0 0 3 4 5 6
a2 <- c(a[1:2], 0, 0, a[5:6])       #giving              [1] 1 2 0 0 5 6
a3 <- c(a[1:4], 0, 0)               #giving              [1] 1 2 3 4 0 0
```

What I'm trying to do is multiply all three blocks with the matrix, and binding the results into one matrix:

```
c <- rbind(a1 %*% b, a2 %*% b, a3 %*% b)
```

that results in a matrix c:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   86  194  302  410  518  626
[2,]   66  150  234  318  402  486
[3,]   30   90  150  210  270  330
```

Of course my code here is very clunky, and not possible to use with very large vectors / matrices. Is there a loop code that would allow to do these calculations quickly?

Comment: I'm confused about the *"3 blocks of zeroes for "a""*; how do you generate these vectors from `a`? What are the rules?

Comment: It's just an example. I would like r to define certain blocks of elements inside of a vector to zero. Then repeat until all possible blocks have been considered

Comment: The blocks are not randomly defined. In this example, I chose 3 blocks with zeroes. I could have also chosen 2 blocks with 3 elements equal to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I define my vector and matrix.

```
# Data definitions
a <- c(1:6)
b <- matrix(1:36, nrow = 6, ncol = 6)
```

Next, I create a function that produces a list of your `a` values. It defaults to blocks of zeros that are length two.

```
# Define blocks of zeroes in vector 
define_block <- function(v, n = 2){
  # Check that v is a multiple of n
  if(length(v)%%n)warning("Vector not a multiple of block length")

  # Define blocks of zeroes
  lapply(1:(length(v)/n), function(x)replace(v, ((x-1)*n + 1):(x*n), 0))
}
```

Here, I apply the function:

```
# Create lists of blocks
block_list <- define_block(a)
```

which produces,

```
# [[1]]
# [1] 0 0 3 4 5 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 0 0 5 6
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 0 0
```

Finally, I run through `block_list` and perform your calculation and bind the results together using `do.call` with `rbind`.

```
# Run through block list and bind result into a matrix
do.call(rbind, lapply(block_list, function(x)x%*%b))


#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   86  194  302  410  518  626
#[2,]   66  150  234  318  402  486
#[3,]   30   90  150  210  270  330
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!